# Shipping Methods details table magento2

Tags: magento2.3.1

i would like to know flatrate details store database table

Comment: Do you want to know the table name?

Comment: yes i want table name

Answer (score 1):

As mention in the description, Flatrate Shipping Method store Data in ***shipping_tablerate*** table and other shipping methods store data in ***quote_shipping_rate*** table. Thank You

Comment: sir can you explain how to fetch carrier_title and method_title from quote_shipping_rate  table in magento 2

Comment: please check this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html and accept the answer for help to other